# How can I watch something that's part of an included view with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
<tab heading="Topic Search">
   <div data-ng-controller="AdminGridQuestionSubjectController">
      <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-question-subject.html'"></ng-include >
   </div>
<div>
```

In the controller I have:

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedSubject', function () {
        if ($scope.selectedSubject != null) {
            gridService.getTopicSelect($scope);
            gridService.getQuestionStatusSelect($scope);
        }
    })
```

In the included grid-question-subject.html view I have:

```
  <select
     data-ng-disabled="subjects.length == 0"
     data-ng-model="selectedSubject"
     data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in subjects">
     <option style="display: none" value="">Select Subject</option>
  </select>
```

It seems like the watch is not working as when I make changes in the view then the watch does not
trigger.  Is this because the include view is getting loaded after the page has been compiled.

Please note that everything worked fine until I put my select code into an include. When it was inline everything worked fine :-(

Can anyone give me some idea of how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not seen your completed code but I am pretty sure that selectedSubject is a primitive type. So just modify your code just as below .

Option -1 Better Approach

```
In controller 

  $scope.data= { selectedSubject: '' };
              $scope.$watch('data.selectedSubject', function () {
                  if ($scope.data.selectedSubject!= null) {
                      alert("changed");
                  }
              })


and in template 

<select
     data-ng-disabled="subjects.length == 0"
     data-ng-model="data.selectedSubject"
     data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in subjects">
     <option style="display: none" value="">Select Subject</option>
  </select>
```

Option 2 just change the template as below

```
<select
     data-ng-disabled="subjects.length == 0"
     data-ng-model="$parent.selectedSubject"
     data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in subjects">
     <option style="display: none" value="">Select Subject</option>
  </select>
```

Reason :https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I am sorry I should have mentioned. The code works fine when it appears inline. It does not work when I use ng-include. Sorry and I will add that to the question. Does this make a difference to your answer? Based on what I missed out I don't think the first answer you gave me would help.  Please correct me if I am wrong. I am guessing this is all a scope problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Rather than do it the way you suggested with selectedSubject.name could I just create an object called $scope.data and then pass that around. If that's possible could you show me how I could do that. I think it would look more clean. Thank you very much for your help. I upvoted but didn't yet mark as correct yet.